# I don't have playstation plus and deleted my saved data

Tags: ps4, playstation-plus

I don't have PlayStation plus and deleted my saved data if I subscribe to PS plus will my deleted data be there? I have used all my trials and I DO NOT have PS plus this current moment. So shall I purchase it to get my save data back or am I wasting my money?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, your most recent data is gone.

If you previously used PS+ trial and had auto-upload enabled, it's possible that your saves were uploaded during that trial time. You can check if you have auto-upload enabled in "Settings > System" (see [Auto update/download on PS4](https://www.playstation.com/en-gb/get-help/help-library/games/installing--downloading---updating/how-to-set-up-auto-update-download-on-your-playstation-4/)).

So, in the best case you can restore your old saves if you purchase PS+ now.

See also [Data management on PS4](https://www.playstation.com/en-gb/get-help/help-library/system---hardware/storage---data/manage-ps4-saved-game-data-in-system-storage/).